# Does Helm respect the default section in a JSON schema for values.yaml?

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

If I create a Helm chart and I define a schema, I know that I can run `Helm lint` to check the validity of my `values.yaml`, but if I were to define `default` settings values in the `values.schema.json`, and *not* define those in the `values.yaml`, would Helm insert those default values?

Is there actually any use for the `default` section of a schema, even in linting?

**Example Schema**

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "default": {},
    "examples": [],
    "required": [
        "metadata"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "metadata": {
            "$id": "#/properties/metadata",
            "type": "object",
            "default": {
                "namespace": "my-namespace"
            },
            "examples": [],
            "required": [
                "namespace"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "namespace": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/metadata/properties/namespace",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "my-namespace",
                    "examples": [ ]
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

**Example values.yaml**

Notice the default value for metadata is missing. Is there a way to get Helm (3) to put in the default from the schema?

```yaml
metadata:
  # This is commented out
  # namespace: my-namespace

deploymentSpecs:
  replicas: 1
```

Comment: I'm surprised I haven't seen more people asking for this. This is a github request that was closed: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8218

Answer (score 0):

As noted by another comment, as of 2023, [Helm does not respect the default value](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8218), nor does it uses the value at all (so if you reference it in your template with `{{ .Values.XX }}`, it will be set to `nil` instead.

As a workaround, you can define a new variable with its default value:

```
{{- define "component.xx" -}}
{{- default "HELLO" .Values.XX }}
{{- end -}}
```

And then include it where you need it in your template:

```
{{ include "component.xx" . }}
```